# mod_cache モジュールから `cache: error returned while trying to return disk cached data` が出てキャッシュされなくなる

Tags: apache, mod-cache

お世話になります

Webページにアクセスした際に、画像や CSS, JS などを別サーバから読むようにして、
そちらを、キャッシュするようにしております。
キャッシュには、 Apache の `mod_cache` を使っているのですが、
アクセスが増大するタイミングで、以下のエラーが出て、その後、
まったくキャッシュしなくなるという問題が起きており、ちょっと困っております

```
[Mon Jan 05 09:43:37 2015] [error] (103)Software caused connection abort: cache: error returned while trying to return disk cached data
```

conf設定ファイルは以下のようになっております

```
##############################
#
# Location  Area
#
##############################
<Location "/qr_cu/">
    ProxyPass balancer://panda_customer_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse balancer://panda_customer_cluster/
</Location>

<Location "/qr_cl/">
    ProxyPass balancer://panda_client_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse balancer://panda_client_cluster/
</Location>

<Location "/portal_cu/">
    ProxyPass balancer://koala_customer_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse balancer://koala_customer_cluster/
</Location>

<Location "/idv_tl/">
    ProxyPass balancer://tool_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse balancer://tool_cluster/
</Location>

<Location "/tgb_cu/">
    ProxyPass balancer://owl_customer_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse balancer://owl_customer_cluster/
</Location>

<Location "/tgb_cl/">
    ProxyPass balancer://owl_client_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse balancer://owl_client_cluster/
</Location>

##############################
#
# Proxy balancer Area
#
##############################

<Proxy balancer://panda_customer_cluster>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    BalancerMember http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://panda_client_cluster>
    BalancerMember http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://koala_customer_cluster>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    BalancerMember http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://tool_cluster>
    BalancerMember http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://owl_customer_cluster>
    BalancerMember http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://owl_client_cluster>
    BalancerMember http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Proxy>

##############################
#
# Chache Area
#
##############################
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
    <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
        CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
        CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
        CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie User-Agent Vary Cookie Server
        CacheDefaultExpire 86400
        CacheRoot /var/www/xxxxxx/image/cache
        CacheEnable disk /qr_cu/
        CacheEnable disk /qr_cl/
        CacheEnable disk /portal_cu/
        CacheEnable disk /idv_tl/
        CacheEnable disk /tgb_cu/
        CacheEnable disk /tgb_cl/
        CacheDirLevels 6
        CacheDirLength 3
        CacheMaxFileSize 10000000
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

この辺り([Apache/mod_cache: “Error 103 Software caused connection abort”](https://serverfault.com/questions/491309/apache-mod-cache-error-103-software-caused-connection-abort))とか見てるのですが、明確な回答が見つかってないようなのですが、心当たりのある方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

追記です

回答ありがとうございます。
コネクション数を上げることを試してみたのですが、あまり変わりませんでした。
ただ、その確認の際に、空きメモリを確認したところ、120MBくらいしか平均で残っておらず、アクセスが増大したタイミングで、それを全て食いつぶしてるのではないかと推測していますが、いかがでしょうか。

```
-bash-4.1$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3924856    3803180     121676          0    1529244    1146440
-/+ buffers/cache:    1127496    2797360
Swap:     2097148      13844    2083304
```

さらに追記です。mod_proxyのエラーが出ていましたので、そちらも追記します

以下のエラーがアクセス増大時に出てます。

```
[Mon Jan 05 12:06:56 2015] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) failed
[Mon Jan 05 12:06:56 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
[Mon Jan 05 12:08:29 2015] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) failed
[Mon Jan 05 12:08:29 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
[Mon Jan 05 12:14:19 2015] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) failed
[Mon Jan 05 12:14:19 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

mod_proxyのエラーのようですが。。。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: mod-cacheのタグを追加しました。

Comment: CacheDefaultExpireが24時間になっていますので(元の値は1時間だったはず)、これを短くしてみてはいかがですか。

Comment: キャッシュを一旦全部消してから、一時間にして対応してみたのですが、変わらずでした。。。

Comment: まず mod_proxy のエラーですが、これは接続先から300秒経過してもデータがやって来ないという事です。5分も待つ必要な無いと思いますので、タイムアウトを短くしていただけますか。具体的には Apache の config ファイルで、例えば「Timeout 30」という設定を追加してみて下さい。プロキシサーバとしてお使いないので本来は「ProxyTimeout」を設定することになるのですが、デフォルト値は「Timeout」から引き継ぐので、Timeout を設定します。# 30秒でも長いかもしれません

Comment: @heliac2001さん、ありがとうございます。やってみます！

Answer (score 4):

以下は mod_cache のソースコード(mod_cache.c)の一部分で、例のエラーメッセージが出力されている部分です。

```
/* kick off the filter stack */
out = apr_brigade_create(r->pool, r->connection->bucket_alloc);
rv = ap_pass_brigade(r->output_filters, out);
if (rv != APR_SUCCESS) {
    if (rv != AP_FILTER_ERROR) {
        ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_ERR, rv, r->server,
                     "cache: error returned while trying to return %s "
                     "cached data",
                     cache->provider_name);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

問題の原因は、`ap_pass_brigade` が false を返しているからですが、ではなぜ false を返すのかと言えば、その前の `ap_brigate_create` に問題がありそうなのです。手元に実環境がないので断定は出来ないのですが、Apache サーバのプロセスかスレッドにアクセスが集中してコネクションプールが逼迫しているのではないか、と推測しています。
確か、Apache の設定に最大コネクション数を設定する変数があったのではないかと記憶しているのですが(間違っていたらごめんなさい)、それを増加させてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
コネクション数を上げることを試してみたのですが、あまり変わりませんでした。
ただ、その確認の際に、空きメモリを確認したところ、120MBくらいしか平均で残っておらず、アクセスが増大したタイミングで、それを全て食いつぶしてるのではないかと推測していますが、いかがでしょうか。 -bash-4.1$ free total used free shared buffers cached Mem: 3924856 3803180 121676 0 1529244 1146440 -/+ buffers/cache: 1127496 2797360 Swap: 2097148 13844 2083304

Comment: すみません、効果がなかった様ですね。今回は disk cache なので空きメモリ量が関係するのかどうかは分かりませんね。。。それと、アクセスの集中時にApacheのエラーログにその他のエラーメッセージが出ていないのかどうかが気になりますね。

Comment: 今日のアクセス増大が１２時から再度始まっていて、そのタイミングでmod_proxyのエラーが出ております。回答の方に記載しますね
お手数おかけします

Comment: @shunsuke_stackoverflow 回答への返信はコメント欄でお願いします。また、追加情報を載せる場合には質問を編集する形でお願いします（追記といった形で載せるとわかりやすいと思います）。

Comment: 失礼しました。ありがとうございます。
一つ回答は削除しました

Answer (score 2):

ちょっと情報が古いのでまったく自信がないのですが、[キャッシュを飛ばして CacheDirLength を 2 から 1 にした](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=882600) 的な対応で緩和(？)したような例もあるようです。サブディレクトリの数が減ったことによる効果ですかね？( ext2/3 で有効かも)

あと、質問内にある SO の情報は Apache/2.2.14 とのことだったので 
[Changes](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.2) を眺めてみたのですが `mod_cache` で、ちょくちょく修正がかかっているように読めます。

最近も、 Vary header での Thundering Herd 問題と戦った痕跡があります。( CacheLock との併用時の話っぽいので本件とは関係無さそうです)

これも自信がないですが 2.2 系の最新か、 2.4.x にすると問題は解決するかもしれません。

(あとは、キャッシュして頑張っている努力が台無しになりそうですが、 Vary header を調整して、ディスクI/O に変化を与えてみるとか。。)

Comment: キャッシュを飛ばして〜はやってないので、明日社の他のものと相談して試してみますね

結果出たら追記します

Answer (score 2):

mod_cache のエラーメッセージについては Red Hat に情報がありました。

[Error, apache, 103 Software caused connection abort](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/139873)
(閲覧にはサブスクリプション契約が必要)

内容を要約すると、

- ブラウザで読み込み中にストップを押すなど、TCP接続が中止された場合にこのエラーメッセージが出る。
  バージョン 2.4.x ではデバッグレベルのログに変更された。
- 実際に問題になっているようなら、ネットワークなど、他の原因を探るべし。

とのことです。

mod_proxy のエラーメッセージと合わせての推測となりますが、Backend に接続待ちの間にブラウザ側でタイムアウトしてブラウザと httpd の接続が中止、結果として mod_cache のエラーメッセージが出ているのではないでしょうか。httpd の Timeout をブラウザのタイムアウト値よりも短くして、サーバー側で先にタイムアウトさせてしまえば、mod_cache のエラーメッセージは抑制できるかもしれません。

mod_proxy の方は、Backend への接続でタイムアウトですので、Backend 側の処理が間に合っていない状況になっていると思います。
障害発生時に mod_proxy 側で "netstat -tan" (Linux を想定)の出力に SYN_SENT が多くなっている状況。
それぞれの負荷を調べるとか、OS のリソース不足などのエラーメッセージが出ていないか(/var/log/messages など)とか、確認するといいと思います。

メモリ使用量については、buffers (ブロックデバイスのキャッシュ)が多いですね。これ自体は問題ではないと思いますが、io_wait が多い(vmstat の wa 欄)ようならば、ディスク書き込み待ちになっているので、httpd 側の負荷(ロードアベレージ)が上がる原因になります。

Comment: なるほどです。zabbixから、CPU負荷が高いですというアラートが上がってたので、可能性は高いですね。
Y!トップに掲載された時間にアクセスが集中してしまい、Taichi Yanagiyaさんがおっしゃてることが起きてるのではないかと思われますね。

/var/log/messageも見たのですが、あまり大したものは出てなかった気が。。。ちょっと確認してみます

>httpd の Timeout をブラウザのタイムアウト値よりも短くして、サー>バー側で先にタイムアウトさせてしまえば、mod_cache のエラーメッセ>ージは抑制できるかもしれません。

これも試してみます！